# Check in a program if stderr is redirected to stdout

Tags: c++, winapi, posix, iostream

From within a C++ program, is it possible to check whether stderr is redirected into stdout or vice versa? Basically I want to know if those two file descriptors point to the same place. Platform-specific solutions using native APIs are OK.

Comment: Try GetFinalPathNameByHandle.  I'm not sure whether it works for pipes or not, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Tried `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` on Windows 7, and unfortunately it didn't work for `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`. It failed, with `GetLastError()` returning `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

Answer (score 3):

Linux, possibly other unix-likes as well: fstat both fds and compare dev:ino pairs.

Comment: This seems to work well for my needs, thanks! Now I just need a solution for Windows...

Answer (score 1):

for windows 7 and later console handles - this is real file handles (on XP this is not true, about vista - not remember). we can got this 2 handles by call [GetStdHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE and STD_ERROR_HANDLE. but then need somehow compare files by handle. this not equal direct compare handles values - because 2 different handles can point to same file. even if we got pointer to FILE_OBJECT from handle (this possible from user mode) - two different FILE_OBJECTs can point to same file (if we speak about filesystem files). so best way here i think - got names of both files - and compare - are they equal. this can be done by [ZwQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). code can be like this

```
NTSTATUS QueryName(HANDLE hFile, PUNICODE_STRING Name)
{
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION poni;
    };

    static volatile UCHAR guz;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 512;
    NTSTATUS status;

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryObject(hFile, ObjectNameInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            return RtlDuplicateUnicodeString(0, &poni->Name, Name);
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL || status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW);

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS AreFilesTheSame(HANDLE h1, HANDLE h2, PBOOL pb)
{
    if (h1 == h2)
    {
        *pb = TRUE;
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (!h1 || !h2)
    {
        *pb = FALSE;
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    UNICODE_STRING name1, name2;
    NTSTATUS status;

    if (0 <= (status = QueryName(h1, &name1)))
    {
        if (0 <= (status = QueryName(h2, &name2)))
        {
            *pb = RtlEqualUnicodeString(&name1, &name2, TRUE);
            RtlFreeUnicodeString(&name2);
        }
        RtlFreeUnicodeString(&name1);
    }

    return status;
}

BOOL b;
AreFilesTheSame(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), &b);
```

but for xp this will be not work

Comment: Thank you! I finally got to compile & link this code on Windows 7, but unfortunately it doesn't work as desired. Even when launching the program with `2>&1`, the names are different, e.g. `\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execut`... for stdout vs. `\KnownDlls`... for stderr. Does this code work as desired for you?

Comment: Also when a given handle is a pipe, i.e. when the output of the program is redirected into the input of another program, `NtQueryObject()` fails with `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_INVALID` (0xc0000039).

Comment: @usta - \KnownDlls... for stderr ?? REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execut... for stdout  ?? you confuse handles how minimum